# Installing a conda package with build arguments

Tags: anaconda, conda, package-managers

I am wondering if it is possible to install a conda package and pass arguments to the package being built. In `homebrew`, one can do `brew install emacs --with-cocoa`, `brew install ffmpeg --with-x265`, etc. However, `conda install -c conda-forge emacs --with-cocoa` tries to pass `--with-cocoa` to `conda install`, which fails. Is it possible to pass these sorts of arguments to `conda`'s build process? Perhaps something like `conda install -c conda-forge emacs --build-args="--with-cocoa"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell the answer is no you can not. However, you may use something like [Conda build recipes](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/build-packages/recipe.html) to customize your installations.

For your emacs example, this may be of use: https://github.com/conda/conda-recipes/tree/master/emacs to getting a better understanding.

I do not know if this satisfies your use case requirement. If not, I'll knock this answer down and see if there is a more plausible solution. Hope that it was of some help!